# no viable alternative at character '\' dynamic soql issue

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, soql-injection

I have below method which gets called from page by supplying the search keywords:

```
public PageReference runIntermediariesSearch() {

    soql = intermediariesSoql + ' where Name != null ';

    if (string.isNotBlank(dbAssetsLowerBound))
        soql += ' and Total_DB_Assets__c >=\''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(dbAssetsLowerBound)+'\'';
    if (string.isNotBlank(dbAssetsUpperBound))
        soql += ' and Total_DB_Assets__c <=\''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(dbAssetsUpperBound)+'\'';
    //
      rest of the code   
    //
    string finalQuery = String.escapeSingleQuotes(soql);
    intermediaries = Database.query(finalQuery); // intermediaries is nothing but list of the object
    return null;
}
```

when i run this i am getting the below error:

```
System.QueryException: line 1:318 no viable alternative at character '\'.
```

when i tried to debug the query :

```
select Id, Name, Assets_under_Advisement__c, Total_AUM__c, Total_DB_Assets__c , Total_DC_Assets__c, Total_E_F_Assets__c,
  Total_PS_Assets__c, Hedge_Mgr__c, Fund_of_Funds_Mgr__c, Instit_Mgr__c ,
  Private_Eq_Mgr__c, RE_Mgr__c, Financial_Adv__c, Country__c 
from intermediary__c 
where Total_DB_Assets__c >=\'10\' and Total_DB_Assets__c <=\'20\'
```

I tried to fix it but no luck. Can any one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query against numbers, not strings. Your final `WHERE` clause should look like:

```
WHERE Total_DB_Assets__c >= 10
AND Total_DB_Assets__c <= 20
```

So your `String` manipulation should look like:

```
Integer min;
Integer max;
try
{
    if (String.isNotBlank(dbAssetsLowerBound))
        min = Integer.valueOf(dbAssetsLowerBound);
    if (String.isNotBlank(dbAssetsUpperBound))
        max = Integer.valueOf(dbAssetsUpperBound);
}
catch (TypeException ex)
{
    return new List<SObject>(); // try not to pass around null collections
}

if (min != null)
    whereClauses.add('Total_DB_Assets__c  >= ' + min);
if (max != null)
    whereClauses.add('Total_DB_Assets__c <= ' + max);
```

Note that you no longer really need `String.escapeSingleQuotes` because if any are contained in your inputs they will throw a `TypeException`. It may affect your security scanner results not to use it though...here I favored brevity.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I did the same before checking your answer. Just forgot to update the answer here.

Comment: We should be using dynamic SOQL binding instead anyways: `whereClauses.add('Total_DB_Assets__c >= :min');` This method won't trip security scans, either.

Comment: Yeah I'm a little wary of putting myself in a situation where renaming a variable can cause a runtime error though, which makes me leery of merging variables into dynamic `SOQL` in that way.